# Import `spyOn` function to get rid of 'not defined' eslint error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, eslint

I have a unit test that uses `spyOn` method from `jest`.

```
import React from 'react';
import expect from 'jest-matchers';
import PointsAwardingPage from '../PointsAwardingPage';
import PointsAwardingForm from '../children/PointsAwardingForm';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

it("should call change method in form", () => {
  // given
  spyOn(PointsAwardingPage.prototype, 'change').and.callThrough();
  const form = shallow(<PointsAwardingPage />).find('PointsAwardingForm');

  // when
  form.props().onChange();

  // then
  expect(PointsAwardingPage.prototype.change).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Everything works well. However, I see the following `eslint` error message regarding the `spyOn` function call.

*`spyOn is not defined (no-undef)`*.

Which `import` statement can I use in order to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although a `global` comment is a valid solution, I believe you could simply use `jest.spyOn()` instead.

Don't forget to define `jest` in your `.eslintrc`:

```
"env": {
    "jest": true
}
```

Comment: Oh didn't know that - Does this auto 'define' jest's globals etc for you?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Exactly (https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments)

Comment: Now I'm getting this error after doing that. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'callThrough' of undefined`

Comment: I'm not aware of such syntax in Jest, but a spy will carry the original implementation (which is similar to Jasmine's `callThrough`)

Answer (score 2):

That's because `spyOn` is provided by the test environment - in your case Jest - thus it's not defined by you.

ESLint looks for definitions in *your* code only.

An easy and safe way to get rid of it is to place a comment `/*global spyOn*/` at the top of your test file, which tells ESLint that you have defined it, without actually doing so.